# illegal start of simple expression

Tags: for-loop, playframework, twirl

I am trying to execute a simple java program using play. I am getting a compilation error as illegal start of simple expression. I have searched answers for this question, but I didn't get it. My code looks like this:

```
@(products :List[Product])
@main("Products catalogue")
<h1> All Products </h1>
<table class="table table-striped">
<thead>
<tr>
<th> EAN </th>
<th> NAME </th>
<th> DESCRIPTION </th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
@for(product <- products)
{
<tr>
<td><a href="@routes.Products.details(product.ean)"> @product.ean </a></td>
<td><a href="@routes.Products.details(product.ean)"> @product.name </a></td>
<td><a href="@routes.Products.details(product.ean)"> @product.description  </a></td>
</tr>
}
</tbody>
</table>
```

I am getting the error at the for loop. Can u help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Please add the tag for `play framwork`. So, respective person may reach up to your question.

Comment: You need to surround your html with curly braces- from just before <h1> to the end of file

Comment: thank u. But  i am getting error at main like:  missing arguments for method apply in object main; follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function .... after surrounding html with curly braces. what's the solution?

Comment: Please add screen shots of the errors you are getting so I can assist you further

Answer (score 1):

curly braces must be on the same line as `@for`

```
@for(product <- products){
```

Take attention on the values in scala template if you use java in the play app. For example `product.ean` would work only if you declare `ean` property as `public` in the class `Product`. If you use classic bean then you need to write method name, like `product.getEan`

I did verification of your code and it works correctly:

*models/Product.java*

```
package models;

public class Product{
  private String ean;
  private String name;
  private String description;

  public Product(){};

  public String getEan(){
    return ean;
  }

  public void setEan(String ean){
    this.ean = ean;
  }

  public String getName(){
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name){
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getDescription(){
    return description;
  }

  public void setDescription(String description){
    this.description = description;
  }

}
```

*controllers/Application.java*

```
package controllers;

import play.*;
import play.mvc.*;

import views.html.*;

import models.Product;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Application extends Controller {

    public Result index() {
        List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();

        Product product1 = new Product();
        product1.setName("p 1");
        product1.setEan("ean_1");
        product1.setDescription("description 1");

        products.add(product1);
        return ok(index.render(products));
    }

}
```

*conf/routes*

```
# Home page
GET     /                           controllers.Application.index()
```

*views/index.scala.html*

```
@(products :List[Product])
<h1> All Products </h1>
<table class="table table-striped">
<thead>
<tr>
<th> EAN </th>
<th> NAME </th>
<th> DESCRIPTION </th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
@for(product <- products){
<tr>
<td><a href="@routes.Application.index()"> @product.getEan </a></td>
<td><a href="@routes.Application.index()"> @product.getName </a></td>
<td><a href="@routes.Application.index()"> @product.getDescription  </a></td>
</tr>
}
</tbody>
</table>
```

**result:**

```
<h1> All Products </h1>
<table class="table table-striped">
<thead>
<tr>
<th> EAN </th>
<th> NAME </th>
<th> DESCRIPTION </th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

<tr>
<td><a href="/"> ean_1 </a></td>
<td><a href="/"> p 1 </a></td>
<td><a href="/"> description 1  </a></td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your view needs to be:

```
@(products :List[Product])
@main("Products catalogue") {
<h1> All Products </h1>
<table class="table table-striped">
<thead>
<tr>
<th> EAN </th>
<th> NAME </th>
<th> DESCRIPTION </th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
@for(product <- products) {
<tr>
<td><a href="@routes.Products.details(product.ean)"> @product.ean </a></td>
<td><a href="@routes.Products.details(product.ean)"> @product.name </a></td>
<td><a href="@routes.Products.details(product.ean)"> @product.description  </a></td>
</tr>
}
</tbody>
</table>
}
```